# Get the next whole minute C++

Tags: c++

I want to calculate next whole minute for a given timestamp.

Time stamps are recorded into __int64 variable. I use function TimeStamp2CCYYMMDD_HHmmSS to print the values in YYYYMMDD HHMMSS format.

see examples below.

e.g. For timestamp 20140822 093415, Next whole minute is 20140822 093500

Please help me NextWholeMinute() function.

```
__int64 Now()    //TimeStamp2CCYYMMDD_HHmmSS --> 20140822 093415
{
    __int64      ts;

    time_t  ts32;
    time( &ts32 );
    ts = ts32;

    return ts;
}

__int64 NextMinute()      //gives me 20140822 093515
{
   return Now() + 60 * TicksPerSecond();
}

__int64 NextWholeMinute()      //I want --> 20140822 093500
{
   .....??
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this work?

```
__int64 NextWholeMinute()      //I want --> 20140822 093500
{
   __int64 nextMinute = NextMinute();
   __int64 ticksIntoMinute = nextMinute % (60 * TicksPerSecond());
   return nextMinute - ticksIntoMinute;
}
```